# Impedir dados de aparecer na pesquisa MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela composta pelas seguintes colunas, `ID`, `Produto`, `Compra`, `Venda` e `Resultado`.

Conheço a sintaxe pra selecionar os valores que eu quero, Exemplo:

```
Select * From tabela_exemplo where Produto = '030';
```

Porém, gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar algo que seja do tipo: *Selecionar todas as colunas quando o Produto for igual a 30, porém, do resultado dessa busca, não quero que apareça os resultados cuja a compra seja menor do que 0*.

Seria essa a ideia, mas não sei como aplicar.

At1
Tinha me expressado mal na pergunta, acho que agr fica mais fácil de enteder.

Comment: Caso o produto e compra forem menores do que 0, aí você não vai querer selecionar todas as colunas ?

Comment: Eu me expressei mal na pergunta, na vdd, eu gostaria que ele buscasse todos os produtos iguais a 30, e dessa busca não aparecesse os valores da coluna Compra que sejam menor do que 0.

Comment: Dá pra você editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select * From tabela_exemplo where Produto = '030' and Compra >= 0
```

Comment: Não deveria ser `Compra >= 0`? Pois a pergunta diz *exceto quando*, ou seja, registros que possuem `Compra < 0` não devem ser incluídos.

Comment: Editei a resposta, e analisando melhor, acho que nenhuma das duas está certo... O OP fala "exceto quando **produto** e compra forem menores que zero". Está confuso.

Comment: Realmente digitei errado ali, ignore o produto, seria: "exceto quando as compras forem menores do q 0."
Acho que me expressei mal na pergunta, na vdd, eu quero que ele busque todos os produtos iguais a 030, e dessa busca, não apareça os valores abaixo de 0

Comment: Então está certo :D

Comment: Reeditei a pergunta, acho que agr ficou claro

Comment: Está certo a consulta que coloquei, você testou? Caso tenha resolvido seu problema pode marcá-la como correta no "V" ao lado.

Answer (score 4):

Se você que que retorne os Produtos = 30 a sua própria query retorna isso certo.

```
Select * From tabela_exemplo where Produto = '030';
```

Agora para filtra os Produtos = 30 e Compras >= 0, se isso for o campo da sua tabela bastaria usar o [AND](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and.php) e o uso dos [OPERADORES](http://ftp.tcrc.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/comparison-operators.html)

```
 Select * From tabela_exemplo where Produto = '030' and Compra >= 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Cara nesse caso você precisa informar duas condições no `WHERE` do seu `SELECT`:

```
 SELECT * FROM  tabela_exemplo WHERE Produto = '030' AND Compra >= 0;
```

> Os operadores AND, OR e NOT
>
> A cláusula WHERE pode ser combinada com operadores AND, OR e NOT.
>
> os operadores AND e OR são usados para filtrar registros com base em
>   mais de uma condição:
>
> O operador AND exibe um registro se todas as condições separadas por
>   AND forem VERDADEIRAS.
>
> O operador OR exibe um registro se qualquer uma das condições
>   separadas por OR for VERDADEIRA.
>
> O operador NOT exibe um registro se a(s) condição(s) NÃO FOR(EM)
>   VERDADEIRA(S).